# Why is a lower bound necessary in proofs of VC-dimensions for various examples of hypotheses?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning, vc-theory

In the book "Foundations of Machine Learning" there are examples of proving the VC dimensions for various hypotheses, e.g., for axis-aligned rectangles, convex polygons, sine functions, hyperplanes, etc.

All proofs first derive a lower bound, and then show an upper bound.  However, why not just derive the upper bound since the definition of VC dimension only cares about the **"largest"** set that can be shattered by hypothesis set $\mathcal{H}$?  Since all examples ends up with a lower bound matching the upper bound, is the lower bound just helpful/useful to set a target when trying to show an upper bound?

Reference:
From page 41 of this book pdf version
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e923/9469aba4bccf3e36d1c27894721e8dbefc44.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets use the quotes from the book.

> To give an upper bound, we need to prove that no set $S$ of cardinality
>   $d + 1$ can be shattered by $H$

By doing this, we are proving that $\text{VCdim}(H) < d+1$, but it does not necessarily mean $\text{VCdim}(H) = d$. For example, we may go for an easier-to-prove failure like sets with $2d+1$ members, and consequently prove $\text{VCdim}(H) < 2d+1$, although we know $\text{VCdim}(H) = d$. Therefore:

> To give a lower bound $d$ for $\text{VCdim}(H)$, it suffices to show that a set $S$
>   of cardinality $d$ can be shattered by $H$

We need to prove the lower bound as well to show that $d \le \text{VCdim}(H) < d+1$, which implies $\text{VCdim}(H) = d$. The last equality means that for each size $1$ to $d$, $H$ can shatter at least one set $S$ with that size.

Note that for the $2d+1$ example, we will fail to prove $2d \le \text{VCdim}(H)$, therefore $\text{VCdim}(H) \neq 2d$, and consequently we must try to prove a smaller (probably harder to prove) upper bound $d+1$.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand I had some misunderstandings of the equations.

Comment: @MLstudent My pleasure! Glad I could help.